# How do i change color inside of quotation marks fastcoloredtextbox (FCTB)

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to change color of quotation marks and of the text within but it breaks and works like comment.

I need something like custom color theme for c# syntax highlighting in visual studio